# conditional formatting cells which equals to some range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, formatting

in table 1 I have index values form 1 to 100 and I have other table which has some 30 random numbers ranging from 1 to 100 now I want to color the whole rows of only that numbers in 1st table which are in 2nd table range

[image: excel]

**I want to format only 3 and 5 value cells in table 1**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula as condition:

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$3,A2)>0`

[image]

If you want to highlight those ones missing in table 2: check "=0"

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, which will definitely work efficiently, when using conditional formatting. For `MS365` users can use `XMATCH()` else use `MATCH()` function:

[image]

---

• With `XMATCH()`

```
=XMATCH($A2,B$2:B$3)
```

---

• With `MATCH()`

```
=MATCH($A2,B$2:B$3,0)
```

---